# Using VB 2013, I'm having trouble sorting an array of strings on substrings within each string

Tags: vb.net, sorting, visual-studio-2013, arraylist

I think it's pretty simple, but for some reason it's not coming to me...

This is my code so far

```
Dim fileReader As New StreamReader(FOfileToProcess)
Dim sLine As String = ""
Dim fileText As New ArrayList()
Do Until fileReader.EndOfStream()
    sLine = fileReader.ReadLine()
    If Not sLine Is Nothing Then fileText.Add(sLine)
Loop
fileReader.Close()
fileText.Sort(20, 2, Nothing) 'My intention is to sort by the values at zero-based 20 for 2 characters
fileText.Sort(63, 9, Nothing) '... and likewise at zero-based 63 for 9 characters
Dim saText() As String = DirectCast(fileText.ToArray(GetType(String)), String())
File.WriteAllLines(FOfileToProcess + "_sorted", saText)
```

It works, but the '_sorted' file written out is not sorted correctly.  Is it just a matter of correcting my sort fields?  The original sort is a 2-field sort with the primary being column 63 and the secondary being column 20, but since there's only 1 set of parms, I figured to go for the secondary first and end with the primary.

Suggestions?

TIA!

Comment: Why do you still use the obsolete `ArrayList` instead of a `List(Of String)`?

Comment: I don't need to use arraylist; I could use anything. I actually haven't touched a vb program in some time, and the original program that I'm working on updating started out probably in VB5.  I don't have time to convert the entire thing to C#, so I just need to stay in VB for now...

Comment: Cool! I changed the ArrayList to List(of String) and the sort ranges appropriately and voila!

Thanks @TimSchmelter! Much appreciated!

Comment: Then i have misunderstood your requirement. But i'm glad that it works now.

Comment: Ooops... my mistake: I was comparing the files visually and got them mixed up. The sorting is not working correctly... I tried your answer below, but there is no File.ReadLines method.  There is a ReadAllLines method, but it says it's not queryable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use an `ArrayList` as it does not allow you to specify the type of your items. Instead, use a `List(Of T)`.

```
Dim fileText As New List(Of String)
```

Second, the indexes of the `Sort` method are related to the line number, not to a position within the strings (`ArrayList` does not know that you are inserting strings).

```
Dim fileTextSorted = fileText _
    .OrderBy(Function(s) s.Substring(20, 2)) _
    .ThenBy(Function(s) s.Substring(63, 29))
```

If the file contains lines shorter than the required positions of the substrings or empty lines (e.g. one empty line at the file end), then using the VB `Mid` function is to be preferred over the `Substring` which might throw exceptions. Alternatively, you can discard such lines by first applying a `Where` condition: `.Where(Function(s) s.Length >= 72) _` or don't add such lines to the list when reading the file.

Comment: I tried your solution, but the compiler doesn't recognize OrderBy or ThenBy as methods of a List. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Add an `Imports System.Linq` at the top of the code

Comment: Yep. Figured it out just before you posted it. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

[`ArrayList.Sort(Int32, Int32, IComparer)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6th6159(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't sort your strings by substrings. You can just specifiy the range you want to sort, so string 21 to 23 and 64 to 73.

You want to sort by substrings in each string. Can i provide you a more readable approach using LINQ and `ReadLines`/`WriteAllLines`?

```
Dim lines = From line In System.IO.File.ReadLines(FOfileToProcess)
            Where line.Length >= 73
            Let col1 = line.Substring(20, 2)
            Let col2 = line.Substring(63, 9)
            Order By col1 Ascending, col2 Ascending
            Select line
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(FOfileToProcess + "_sorted", lines)
```

Comment: Figured it out. "Imports System.Linq". Duh! Sorry about that.

Comment: I went with Olivier's solution because, I kept getting a type-casting error with this one. I figure it was probably something I was incorrectly translating, but I do appreciate your help.